# WSS 3.0: showing wrong server as Configuration Database Server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, wss-3.0

after moving my configuration db to a different DB server I had some difficulties to get the farm up and running again.

now my eventlog is full of errormessages, that the config-db is not reachable on my old db server.
Operation / Servers in Farm ... /_admin/FarmServers.aspx is still showing the old db server as config db server

I could create a new wss web application and can see the corresponding records in the objects table in the new config db!?

how can I get rid of this artifact?

TIA
Stefan

Comment: Hi, did you get this working? Even i have the same problem. Please post your answer. I gave a direct server name. I have to change its name. Please post your solution.

Comment: Any ideas yet? I moved my server to a new one by doing a full backup of the old server, and full restore on the new server... yet when I go into 'Services on this server' I can pick my old server, and under that is 'Windows SharePoint Services Database'... How can I move this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using. You basically have to find the reference of the parent ID of the new sql server and assign it to the config database row.
check this link to find out more

http://www.sharepointtechs.com/moss-2007-showing-old-server-as-configuration-database-server/

Answer (score 0):

How did you "move" the config DB? If you restore it from a SQL Server backup it will cause conflicts between GUIDs and other data stored there. You should only restore content and search databases. My advice would be to build up the farm again in the new environment.